# $state.go() working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angular-ui-router, passport-local

I'm trying to redirect my user to a dashboard / home view using ui-router's $state.go() method. It works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome, it only works on the second click of the login button. The first click, it'll just sit there. Sometimes, the second click still won't start the state transition, either.

Here's the login code I'm using: '

```
$scope.login = function(user){
    $http.post('/user/login', {
        "username": user.username,
        "password": user.password
    })
    .then(function(user){
        $log.log(user); 
        $state.go('dashboard');
    }, function(err){
        if(err) $state.go('login'); 
    });
}
```

What I don't understand is why in Chrome it will sometimes work after hitting the login button a second time? It's not throwing any errors, either. The console is clean and it's logging my user in the console correctly, so I know the $state.go() method is being reached. It just isn't firing correctly.

I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar issue to this on here.

I'm using ui-router and Passport. I can get $state.go() and ui-router sref links to work everywhere else in my app without any issue, but this login redirect is killing me.

This is the route that I'm trying to load

```
  .state('dashboard', {
url: '/dashboard', 
templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html', 
controller: 'MainController',
resolve: {
  loggedIn: checkLoggedin
}
})
```

And here's the checkLoggedIn method that I'm using as well.

```
  var checkLoggedin = function($q, $timeout, $http, $location, $rootScope, $state){ 
    var deferred = $q.defer(); 
    $http.get('/user').success(function(user){ 
      // Authenticated 
      if (user !== "") {
        deferred.resolve();
      }else { 
        //Not authenticated
        $rootScope.message = 'You need to log in.'; 
        deferred.reject(); 
        $state.go('login'); 
      } 
    }); 
    return deferred.promise; 
  };
```

Comment: what does the route that you are trying to go to look like?

Comment: Why is event.preventDefault there? event is not even defined.

Comment: @Claies It's a dashboard that has a few get requests and that's it. Mostly just a base page for navigation.

Comment: @estus that preventDefault() was from something I was trying earlier, that was an incorrect paste. It's removed now to reflect the correct code I was try to get to work.

Comment: You didn't actually answer my question. I asked what the route looks like, not the page.  Preferably, the router code.

Comment: @Claies I updated the post to reflect the route and the resolve that I'm trying to load after login.

Comment: your code is very inconsistent.  You are using `.then` for some `$http` calls and the depreciated `.success` for others.  On top of that, you appear to be wrapping `$http` which is already a promise inside another `$defer`.  If I had to guess, the deferred is getting rejected for some reason, an you are being redirected back to the page you were just trying to leave, which is causing it to appear that the button didn't do anything.  you should add some `console.log` messages in that function, and don't use `$q.defer` or `.success`